Rudin's RCA 13.11(Simply connected region)
13.11 Theorem
For a plane region $\Omega$, each of the following nine conditions implies all the others.
(a) $\Omega$ is homeomorphic to the open unit disc $U$.
(b) $\Omega$ is simply connected.
(c) $\operatorname{Ind}_\gamma(\alpha)=0$ for every closed path $\gamma$ in $\Omega$ and for every $\alpha \in S^2-\Omega$.
(d) $S^2-\Omega$ is connected.
(e) Every $f \in H(\Omega)$ can be approximated by polynomials, uniformly on compact subsets of $\Omega$.
(f) For every $f \in H(\Omega)$ and every closed path $\gamma$ in $\Omega$,
$$
\int_\gamma f(z) d z=0 .
$$
(g) To every $f \in H(\Omega)$ corresponds an $F \in H(\Omega)$ such that $F^{\prime}=f$.
(h) If $f \in H(\Omega)$ and $1 / f \in H(\Omega)$, there exists a $g \in H(\Omega)$ such that $f=\exp (g)$.
(j) If $f \in H(\Omega)$ and $1 / f \in H(\Omega)$, there exists a $\varphi \in H(\Omega)$ such that $f=\varphi^2$.
Rudin's proof:
$(f)$ implies $(g)$. Assume $(f)$ holds, fix $z_0 \in \Omega$, and put
$$
F(z)=\int_{\Gamma(z)} f(\zeta) d \zeta \quad(z \in \Omega)
$$
where $\Gamma(z)$ is any path in $\Omega$ from $z_0$ to $z$. This defines a function $F$ in $\Omega$. For if $\Gamma_1(z)$ is another path from $z_0$ to $z$ (in $\Omega$ ), then $\Gamma$ followed by the opposite of $\Gamma_1$ is a closed path in $\Omega$, the integral of $f$ over this closed path is 0 , so (1) is not affected if $\Gamma(z)$ is replaced by $\Gamma_1(z)$. We now verify that $F^{\prime}=f$. Fix $a \in \Omega$. There exists an $r>0$ such that $D(a ; r) \subset \Omega$. For $z \in D(a ; r)$ we can compute $F(z)$ by integrating $f$ over a path $\Gamma(a)$, followed by the interval $[a, z]$. Hence, for $z \in D^{\prime}(a ; r)$,
$$
\frac{F(z)-F(a)}{z-a}=\frac{1}{z-a} \int_{[a, z]} f(\zeta) d \zeta,
$$
and the continuity of $f$ at $a$ implies now that $F^{\prime}(a)=f(a)$, as in the proof of Theorem 10.14.
(g) implies (h). If $f \in H(\Omega)$ and $f$ has no zero in $\Omega$, then $f^{\prime} / f \in H(\Omega)$, and $(g)$ implies that there exists a $g \in H(\Omega)$ so that $g^{\prime}=f^{\prime} / f$. We can add a constant to $g$, so that $\exp \left\{g\left(z_0\right)\right\}=f\left(z_0\right)$ for some $z_0 \in \Omega$. Our choice of $g$ shows that the derivative of $f e^{-g}$ is $0$ in $\Omega$, hence $f e^{-g}$ is constant (since $\Omega$ is connected), and it follows that $f=e^g$.
My Questions:

Rudin does not define the index of infinity point. How can I deal with it?

Why can Rudin define $F(z)$ through an integral over path?


Rudin does define what a connected set is but what a path connected set is. Although I know it is equivalent in this case, using it without any explanation is unreasonable. So I suppose there must be some easy ways to prove the existence of a path between $z_0$ and $z$ in the plane region.

How can I deduce that adding a constant to $g$ can get $exp\{g(z_0)\}=f(z_0)$ for some $z_0$?

I have figure it(3) out.


Open connected sets in $\mathbb R^{n}$ are path connected and Rudin has proved this earlier. 2) Any non-zero constant $c$ is of the form $e^{d}$ for some complex number $d$.


@geetha290krm I don't where his proof of (1) is

Here is  a simple exercise for you: Let $U$ be open and connected in $\mathbb R^{n}$, $x \in U$,  and consider the set off all points in $U$ that can be a connected to $x$ by a continuous curve. Show that this set is open and closed in $U$. Use connectedness to conclude that this set is the whole of $U$.

(2) The text you insert here includes Rudin's explanation of why we can define $F$ as an integral over a path. For any two paths connecting $z$ to $z_0$, if one is reversed and the two are combined, you get a closed path and by (f), the integral around it is $0$, which means the integrals along the original two paths are always the same, no matter which two paths are chosen. Since all paths give the same result for the integration, we can define $F(z)$ to be that common result.

(1) Any closed $\gamma$ in $\Bbb C$ is bounded. Outside those bounds, all points in $\Bbb C$ have $0$ index. That means in the Riemann sphere, $\infty$ has neighborhoods in which $\text{ind}\gamma\ p = 0$ for any $p \ne \infty$. This seems adequate enough to me to recognize what value $\text{ind}\gamma\ \infty$ should have.

@PaulSinclair (2) We need to prove, however, that such a path exists connecting $z$ and $z_0$.

It defines $F$ for all points in the path-connected component of $z_0$. By definition of "region", $\Omega$ is open, so that includes some neighborhood of $z_0$. If there are other path components, we just choose additional base points $z_i$ in them and use them to define $F$ in those components. The result is $F$ is defined on all $\Omega$ and $F' = f$. There is no conflict between different components because each point of $\Omega$ is contained in only one, and those components are each open.

@PaulSinclair Whether there exists a possibility that there is not any path connecting some z with z_0

... Yes, and I covered that. You choose a base point $z_i$ in EVERY path component of $\Omega$ and use it to define $F$ on that path-component. This defines $F$ everywhere.

@PaulSinclair In fact, a plane region is an open connected set. Rudin only defines what a connected set(component) is, but path connected set(component). Although I can convince myself with introducing more notions, I think Rudin wants to handle it with as less "tools" as possible.

If $z$ and $z_0$ have a path between them in some open set $A$ then any point in a ball about $z$ in $A$ also has a path to $z_0$. Thus the set of all points in $A$ that have a path to $z_0$ is open. If $z$ does not have a path to $z_0$, then neither does any point in a ball about it in $A$. So the set of all points in $A$ without a path to $z_0$ is also open. Every point of $A$ is in one or the other set, so if both are non-empty, they form a disconnection of $A$. Since $\Omega$ is connected, that cannot be. and there is a ball about $z_0$ in $\Omega$. all of which have a path to $z_0$.

When it goes to chat, I find practically impossible to continue any discussion. When I looked at chat now, I don't see anything from you to respond to.

@PaulSinclair I have figure it out from your answer. I am sorry for "chat", I just unconsciously touch it. Can you write your answer below my questions so that I can "accept" your answer.

(1) Every closed path $\gamma$ in $\Bbb C$ is bounded. $\text{ind}_\gamma p = 0$ for all points outside the bounding circle. In the Riemann Sphere, $\infty$ is a point always outside the bounding circle, so it is only natural to consider $\text{ind}_\gamma \infty = 0$.
(2) Consider the set $U$ of all points $z \in \Omega$ that can be reached by a path from $z_0$ while staying inside $\Omega$. If a point $z_1\in U$, then there is some disk about $z_1$ that is entirely inside $\Omega$. Since every point of that disk connects to $z_1$ by a line segment in the disk, a path can follow the line segment to $z_1$ and then the path from $z_1$ to $z_0$ to connect to $z_0$. Thus the entire disk must lie in $U$. Therefore $U$ is open. Conversely, if $z_2 \in \Omega$, but not in $U$, there is some disk about $z_2$ that lies in $\Omega$. If any point in that disk were in $U$, then the path from $z_0$ to that point, followed by the line segment to $z_2$ connects $z_2$ to $z_0$ by a path in $\Omega$, contradicting that $z_2 \notin U$. Therefore $\Omega \setminus U$ is also open. Since as a region, $\Omega$ is connected, one of these sets must be empty. And since $z_0 \in U$, it cannot be $U$. So $\Omega \setminus U = \emptyset$ and $U = \Omega$. That is, there is a path connecting every element of $\Omega$ to $z_0$.
If there are two paths $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ from $z_0$ to $z$, then the combination of $\gamma_1$ and the reverse of $\gamma_2$ forms a closed path, and if (f) holds, the integral of $f$ about that closed path is $0$. Since integration changes signs when the direction of a path is reversed, this means that $$\int_{\gamma_1}f(z)\,dz = \int_{\gamma_2}f(z)\,dz$$
So all paths in $\Omega$ connecting $z_0$ to $z$ have the same integral, allowing us to define $F(z)$ to be the common value.
(3) $e^z$ takes on all values in $\Bbb C$ except $0$. Since $f$ has no zeros in $\Omega$, $f(z_0) \ne 0$, and neither is $e^{-g(z_0)}f(z_0)$. So there is some $C \in \Bbb C$ with $e^C = e^{-g(z_0)}f(z_0)$.
